# Deserialize Nested JSON, Map to Model and Save

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, deserialization

My initial version was able to take one segment of JSON, Map the "key value" pairs to an object and store it to a database accordingly for example:

```
{
    "msee": 11976.16796875,
    "r2": -0.8027065992355347,
    "std": 109.59520721435547,
    "avg": -2.3448710441589355,
    "min": -386.17926025390625,
    "max": 405.26837158203125,
    "out_file": "test.png"
}
```

I then had my class `ResultData`

```
public class ResultData
    {

        public float Msee { get; set; }

        public float R2 { get; set; }

        ....

    }
```

I took that data and deserialized it:

```
var resultDataModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.ResultData>(content);
```

Mapped the data accordingly

```
var resultData = resultDataModel.ToData();
```

And then saved to DB:

```
await _dataContext.ResultData.AddAsync(resultData);
```

Now the changes I want to make to my code is if my incoming JSON is Nested i.e.

```
{
    "train": {
        "msee": 0.00011604210158111528,
        "r2": 1.0,
        "std": 0.010741780512034893,
        "avg": -0.0009074629051610827,
        "min": -0.022330284118652344,
        "max": 0.2726593017578125,
        "out_file": "train.png"
    },
    "test":{
        "msee": 11976.16796875,
        "r2": -0.8027065992355347,
        "std": 109.59520721435547,
        "avg": -2.3448710441589355,
        "min": -386.17926025390625,
        "max": 405.26837158203125,
        "out_file": "test.png"
    }
}
```

My approach was to create a dictionary and print:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Models.ResultData>>(content);

foreach (var x in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key}: {x.Value}");
}
```

This would output something like

```
train: 0.0001160421  1...
test: 11976.168  -0.8027066 ...
```

My question is how would I do a similar approach to my initial version of code so that it first takes the JSON of `train` in the dictionary, maps it and then stores 1 row AND then it will take that second nested JSON `test`, map the data again accordingly and save as another row.

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? Do you want to insert your `resultDataModel` into the same dictionary?

Comment: Well i want the code to kind of recognise individual JSON components inside that nest so that i can create individual `ResultData` objects..then use my ToData() object and save to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Models.ResultData>>(content);

foreach (var x in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Key}: {x.Value}");
    _dataContext.ResultData.Add(x.Value.ToData());
}

await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```